# NSManagedObject has no member 'allObjects'

Tags: ios, xcode

In my code I have an issue that reads "Value of type 'NSManagedObject' has no member 'allObjects' ". What would I need to include in my code to make the allObjects reference work? I am watching this tutorial on coding this simple app that lists jokes using table views. Thanks in advance!

```
import UIKit


class jokesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var collection: Collection?

    var jokes = [Joke]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.jokes = self.collection?.jokes?.allObjects as! [Joke]
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self

        }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.jokes.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()

        let joke = self.jokes[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = joke.title
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no such property called `allObjects` in `NSManagedObject` class. Property you are referring is of `NSMutableArray` as you have declared `var jokes = [Joke]()` as array of Joke objects.

Comment: So how would I resolve that error in confronting?

Comment: That array is used as `DataSource` for your `UITableView`, why are you accessing it inside collection object as its defined in current class? update following line `self.jokes = self.jokes?.allObjects as! [Joke]` in viewDidLoad.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara thanks for your help, but it's still giving me an error. It now says "Value of type [Joke] has no member 'allObjects'

Comment: The `allObjects` method is used to convert an NSSet into NSArray.  So in your code `self.collection?.jokes?` should be an NSSet, but the error message says it's an NSManagedObject.  That probably means you have defined your relationship as to-one when it should be to-many.  Show the class definition for `Collection` to confirm.

Comment: @pbasdf Thank you for the time you took to write out that message! Both of my relationships are set to "To Many" yet I am still receiving the same error. Any other ideas of what could possibly be wrong? I'm completely new to this material.

Comment: Can you post an image (or a link to an image) of your data model?

Answer (score 0):

For that you should change the object's Relationship Type from "**to One**" to "**to Many**".

[Refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzeuo.png)